# Error Download Page Source use WebClient window phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying make a download on youtube in window phone 8. I have use this code to download a page source:

```
 public void DownloadWebPage(string VideoID)
        {   
string Url="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + VideoID;       
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new   DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new System.Uri(Url));
            //var html = webClient.DownloadStringAsync
        }
        public void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);             
            }
            else
            {              
                html = e.Result;              
            }
        }
```

I don't while it get error "The remove server return an error Not Found". I try with a nother link of a nother page and see it work ok. In window phone 7.1, it's also work with this youtube link. Can any body help me? I will be very thankful for that :)

Comment: Seems like a network problem. Either you are not connected to Internet on that device, or youtube is blocked in the network you have connected to, or your device is going through some proxy that has blocked youtube.

Comment: I think the network is ok, when i create new project, with this code, if i choose "window phone OS 7.1" it run ok and return page source, but if i choose "window phone OS 8.0" it return this error. I have test a lot of.

Comment: I have tried your code with WebRequest. Youtube is sending http status code 402 PaymentRequired. From Wikipedia, 'YouTube uses this status if a particular IP address has made excessive requests, and requires the person to enter a CAPTCHA.' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error). So it might be the reason.

Comment: could you explain for me more? Because in now, project with "window phone OS 7.1" of me still run ok. thank for your help!